# Partial Border Inside a Panel

Tags: asp.net, css, border

What I am trying to do is to create a partial border on the top of my panel.  Eg. I want a portion of the top border to be white out.  Eg. In my css, I have

```
.UserPanel
{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

If I specify a border-top, the entire panel would have a top border.  What I want is a partial border that stretches for about 80% starting from the left.  Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify image for top border with     border-top-image